# Convert JSON record to LinkedHashMap<String,String> using Jackson API

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a JSON file(it contains an array of JSON objects.)
I am trying to read it object by object.
Each object I need to convert it to a `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` where both the key and value are strings. Note that even if the JSON objects contain a non-string value(`Integer/Boolean`), I want my `LinkedHashMap` to contain a string.

This is my JSON file (`films.json`):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fight Club",
    "year": 1999,
  }
]
```

Now, this has 1 object. I want to convert it to a `LinkedHashMap<String,String>`.

So for the above example, my `LinkedHashMap` should contain(for the 1st JSON object) :

> "name" : "Fight CLub"
>
> "year" : "1999"

Notice how the year is `String` in the `LinkedHashMap` and not `Integer`.

This is what I tried.

```
Map<String, Object> myLinkedHashMap;

JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(new File("films.json"));
jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(new File(filePath));
jsonParser.nextToken();

ObjectMapper  mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

while(jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY){
    myLinkedHashMap  = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, LinkedHashMap.class);
}
```

The variable `myLinkedHashMap` will contain a key/value pair for an object in my JSON file.

> But the problem is that for 'year' of the JSON file, I am getting Integer in the LinkedHashMap as the JSON file also contains Integer.

Instead, I want the `Integer` as `String` in the `LinkedHashMap`.

Please help me get `String` in the `LinkedHashMap` instead of `Integer`.

Note: The solution should be generic to other data types also.

So if the JSON object contains boolean `true`, then my `LinkedHashMap` should contain `"true"`.

Comment: why not call `toString` on value while you are using them, `toString` will return `String`

Comment: @Deadpool the code is tightly coupled and changes cant be made there

Comment: you can do this if you can define custom class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct map type using `TypeFactory` and `constructMapType` method to tell exactly what do you need from `readValue` method. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class JsonMapApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        JsonParser jsonParser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(jsonFile);
        jsonParser.nextToken();

        MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(LinkedHashMap.class, String.class, String.class);
        while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, mapType);
            map.forEach((k, v) -> {
                Assert.isInstanceOf(String.class, v);
                System.out.println(k + " -> " + v + " (" + v.getClass().getName() + ")");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
name -> Fight Club (java.lang.String)
year -> 1999 (java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Map<String, Object> myLinkedHashMap;
```

to

```
 Map<String, String> myLinkedHashMap;
```